# Outlook VBA-Download specific, most recent, e-mail excel attachments to local folder + Copy and paste contents

Tags: email, outlook, attachment, email-attachments, office-automation

I'm looking for a VBA macro that scrapes outlook for specific, most recent, e-mails that are received MTWTF, saves the .xlsm and .xlsx attachments in a local folder, then another macro to look in to these recently saved files and paste specific tabs in to an excel workbook.

I receive three daily e-mails with static subjects with only the date changing daily. One of the e-mail attachments has a password on it.

Steps-

1. Search Outlook for the most recent "ABC E-mail subject" and save down attachment in local folder
   1.1) Search Outlook for the most recent "DEF E-mail subject" and save down attachment in local folder
   1.2) Search Outlook for the most recent "XYZ E-mail subject", enter attachment password and save down attachment in local folder
2. Ignore older versions of the same e-mail
3. Look in to the saved down ABC, DEF, and XYZ (again entering the password if needed) files, copy 2+ tabs from each file in to an Excel template

Thank you!!

**What's been tried:
**

On the following code, this object can not be found:

```
fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Dell")
```

I've created the folder in a shared outlook e-mail/group.  I've referenced `MicroSoft 16 object library` in `Tools` > `References`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveOutlookAttachments()

    'This early-binding version requires a reference to the Outlook and Scripting Runtime object libraries
    
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim dir As Scripting.Folder
    Dim dirName As String
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Dell")
    
    For Each i In fol.Items
    
        If i.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set mi = i
            
            If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                'Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime, mi.Attachments.Count
                
                dirName = _
                    "C:\Outlook Files\" & _
                    Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-nn-ss ") & _
                    Left(Replace(mi.Subject, ":", ""), 10)
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirName)
                End If
                
                For Each at In mi.Attachments
                
                    'Debug.Print vbTab, at.DisplayName, at.Size
                    at.SaveAsFile dir.Path & "\" & at.Filename
                    
                Next at
                
            End If
            
        End If
    
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub SaveOutlookAttachmentsLateBinding()

    'This late-binding version allows you to remove the references to the Outlook and Scripting Runtime object libraries
    
    Dim ol As Object    'Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Object    'Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Object   'Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Object    'Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Object    'Outlook.Attachment
    Dim fso As Object   'Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim dir As Object   'Scripting.Folder
    Dim dirName As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject(Class:="Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set ol = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Dell")
    
    For Each i In fol.Items
    
        If i.Class = 43 Then
        
            Set mi = i
            
            If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                'Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime, mi.Attachments.Count
                
                dirName = _
                    "C:\Outlook Files\" & _
                    Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-nn-ss ") & _
                    Left(Replace(mi.Subject, ":", ""), 10)
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirName)
                End If
                
                For Each at In mi.Attachments
                
                    'Debug.Print vbTab, at.DisplayName, at.Size
                    at.SaveAsFile dir.Path & "\" & at.Filename
                    
                Next at
                
            End If
            
        End If
    
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting folders by index from the `Namespace` class:

```
Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Dell")
```

Use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method of the `Namespace` class which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Inbox folder for the user who is currently logged on.

Then instead of iterating over all items in the folder and checking whether each item has attached files:

```
 For Each i In fol.Items
        If i.Class = 43 Then
            Set mi = i
            If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
```

You need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting only items that correspond to the search criteria, so you can iterate over items that has attachments (and if required belong to a specified date range). There is no need to check each item in the folder separately in the loop. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

In cases when you need to check multiple folders you may choose the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

In case if you need to search items for a specific date range, the [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) page describes formats of filtering strings. For example:

```
Dim datStartUTC As Date 
Dim datEndUTC As Date 

datStartUTC = oPA.LocalTimeToUTC(Date) 
datEndUTC = oPA.LocalTimeToUTC(DateAdd("d", 1, Date)) 

 'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
    strFilter = AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " > '" & datStartUTC & "' AND " _ 
    & AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " < '" & datEndUTC & "'" 

 'This call succeeds with @SQL prefix 
    Set colRestrict = colItems.Restrict("@SQL=" & strFilter) 
    'Get count of restricted items 
    Debug.Print (colRestrict.Count)
```

And a small function function to add quotes in VBA:

```
Public Function AddQuotes(ByVal SchemaName As String) As String 
    On Error Resume Next 
    AddQuotes = Chr(34) & SchemaName & Chr(34) 
End Function
```